# Username and password form made with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I am making simple username / password login form for my web page, and am having trouble getting it to work.

I have double checked all of my code, and jsfiddle.net says the code is valid, but when I try to hit "Submit" with the correct username and password, it just pops up with the alert on the last line of the function saying the username/password is incorrect.

JavaScript:

```
 var un = window.document.userform.formuser.value;
 var pw = window.document.userform.formpass.value;
 function findPass()
 {
 if(un + "_" + pw == "demo_demo")
  {window.location.href='../pages/demouser.html';}
  else if (un + "_" + pw == "user2_pass2") {
     window.location.href='pages/user2.html';
  }
  else {alert('Incorrect username/password');}
 }
```

HTML:

```
 <form name="userform" action="javascript:findPass();" style="margin:0;">
 Username:<input type="text" name="formuser"><br>
 Password:<input type="password" name="formpass"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="  Sign In  ">
```

I have googled all over the place, and cannot find a solution to my problem.
Also, the server does not support php, so I prefer using this method.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: First it is not secure, second you are reading the values on page load and not when the user clicks the button.

Comment: @epascarello So how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: stick the un and pw lines inside of the function.

Comment: @epascarello thanks! that worked great! Could you post it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you define these two lines:

```
 var un = window.document.userform.formuser.value;
 var pw = window.document.userform.formpass.value;
```

The page has not loaded yet. Move those lines into your `findPass` method so they they are retrieved when the button is clicked (and after the page has loaded).

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var un = window.document.userform.formuser.value;
 var pw = window.document.userform.formpass.value;
```

When those lines are being evaluated by the browser your form is still empty, you need to assign a handler to your

```html
 <input type="submit" value="  Sign In  ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Like epascarello said: you are reading the values on page load and not when the user clicks the button.

fix this by changing this:

```
<script language="javascript">
var un = window.document.userform.formuser.value;
var pw = window.document.userform.formpass.value;
 function findPass() {
your code ...
 }
```

to this

```
<script language="javascript">
     function findPass() {
var un = window.document.userform.formuser.value;
var pw = window.document.userform.formpass.value;
rest of your code ...
 }
```

Hope this helps you!